# How to check what kind of data send to server in GET method

Tags: html

I want to check what specifc data send to server when I press the GET method 'a' button. Anyway to check? example:

```
<form method="get" action="x">
 <p>
     <input name="key" type="hidden" value="x"></input>
     <input type="submit" value="a">
 </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Use Telerik Fiddler or Wireshark to watch the network traffic.

Answer (score 2):

You can view data sent to backend on browser, in developer tools on network tab you can see all requests and their data sent, for example on chrome:

[image]